How to find the path of created db by react-native-sqlite-storage in the phone
i can't find the file of database created by react-native-sqlite-storage in my app
i need to copie this file and need it's path
i tried to show files with react-native-fs
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath) // On Android, use "RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath" (MainBundlePath is not defined)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('GOT RESULT', result);

    // stat the first file
    return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
  })

but it didn't showed me the db file

All app rivate file less are created inside /data/data/<your_app_packagename>. On unrooted phones this directory is not accessible but for apps marked debuggable you can use Android Studio device explorer to browser the file-system including your app private files. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/2241

thank you very much

i found the path in Android Studio device explorer, But when i trie to access the folder or read the path from the code with RNFS of react-native-fs i get the error of : no such file or directory
